# dll File not accessible

Tags: c#, winforms, dll, webcam, dllimport

I know this question has been asked before but all the steps advised doesn't seem to work for me.

I am trying to use `WebCamLib.dll` to my project but it keeps giving me this error:

> please make sure the file is accessible and that is a valid assembly
>   or com component

I tried to register the dll to `SYSTEM32` and I get this error

> The module C:\WebCamLib.dll" was loaded but the entry-point
>   DllRegisterServer was not found.
>   Make sure that "C:\WebCamLib.dll" is a valid DLL or OCX file and then
>   try again.

Please suggest a way. Thank you in advance.

Comment: WebCamLib is extremely generic name, which web cam library are you trying to use? Without knowing which specific library you are working with we can't help you with your problem. Also, you said you tried some steps, what specific steps did you try?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I am trying to use the Touchless SDK http://touchless.codeplex.com/ I tried to register the dll using regsvr32 <dllpath>

Comment: If you could suggest me some other ways to connect to my webcam even that will do @ScottChamberlain

Answer (score 1):

The library you are trying to use is a managed library, you don't need to register it or use dllimport. Just [add a reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7314433t(v=VS.90).aspx) from inside your project to the dll.

Comment: I tried to add reference that's when I get the error message  "please make sure the file is accessible and that is a valid assembly or com component"

Answer (score -1):

First option is DLL file may be corrupt. Make sure it is working with other applications.

My second opinion is you are trying to use this DLL as COM object which is not.